# Тире или запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Здравствуйте.

1.Если я говорю - ты молчи.

2.Ты молчи,если я говорю.

Почему в первом варианте ставится тире,а во втором - запятая?

Ставится ли запятая в первом варианте?

Подсмотрено в книге.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тире в предложении (1) обозначает авторскую паузу и особую интонацию, при которой логически выделяется местоимение "я".При постановке запятой  интонация обычная: увеличенная пауза отсутствует, тоническое ударение падает на слово "говорю".

Авторское тире чаще всего ставится  в СПП с придаточными уступки, условия, времени, например : Сколько бы ни смотреть на море – оно никогда не надоест. Коли ты честный – не водись с бесчестными. Когда идёшь над бездной – надо прямо смотреть в лазурь и свет.

Обратим внимание на то, что придаточное во всех примерах стоит на первом месте, и такой же порядок мы наблюдаем в БСП при наличии тире, например:Дела не любишь – мастером не будешь.

А вот в предложении (2)  (при обратном порядке простых предложений) авторская пауза не делается, что соответствует постановке запятой. Интонация в этом случае менее выразительная и определенная - тоническое ударение может падать на слово "я" или на слово "говорю".

Таким образом, мы видим, как, меняя структуру предложения, автор может найти наилучший содержательный вариант для своего высказывания.